# how could I modify cell data used same class for column all class in column have same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I want to change table cell data using jquery I want it to be replaced by data that will be taken from the same cell.
eg - older cell data - October 5, 2021, 18:00,
I want it to change to only 18:00.
All the cells have come to class.

I have tried

```
var str1 = $('.service_date').text();
              console.log(str1);
             $.each(str1 , function() { 
              var subStr = str1.substring(str1.length, str1.length-5);
              console.log(subStr);});
```

Comment: `var str1 = $('.service_date').text();` doesn't create an array of strings, it creates a single string containing the text of all matching elements. You need to each over `$('.service_date')` and use `$(this).text()` inside the function. Please always, always check the docs before posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just setting `str1` to the text of the first matching element, not an array of all of them.

Use the `.text()` method with a function argument. This will iterate over all the matching elements, replacing their text with the return value of the function.

```js
$("#update").click(function() {
  $('.service_date').text(function(i, str1) {
    return str1.slice(-5);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Pickup Time</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="service_date">October 5, 2021, 18:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="service_date">December 10, 2021, 18:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="update">Remove dates</button>
```

Comment: column from the table have date and time i want it that get cell data and remove date and print back only time

Comment: That's what this does.

Comment: I added an executable snippet.

Comment: yes it does work